# Writing to a memory mapped text file printing NULL till the end of mapped memory

Tags: c++, c, winapi, visual-c++

In this code, Im writing some text to a memory mapped text file. Data is written to the file successfully, but when i open it with notepad, after the written data, "NULL" is repeatedly written upto the mapped memory limit which is greater than the text i have written.

What could be the possible reason?

```
pLogMsg = (char*)calloc(1024,sizeof(char));
printf("[INFO] entering logger writeback thread\n");

log_file = CreateFile (TEXT("one.txt"),             // Open one.txt.
                    GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,   // Open for reading and writing
                    FILE_SHARE_WRITE,               // file share
                    NULL,                           // No security
                    OPEN_ALWAYS,                    // Open or create
                    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,          // Normal file
                    NULL);                          // No template file
if (log_file == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    printf("%d [ERR] cant open file GLE %d\n",GetCurrentThreadId(),GetLastError());
    return -1;
}
hMapping = CreateFileMapping( log_file, 0, PAGE_READWRITE, 0,4096 ,0 );
if (hMapping == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    printf("%d [ERR] cant create file mapping %d\n",GetCurrentThreadId(),GetLastError());
    return -1;
}
pFileData = (CHAR*)MapViewOfFile( hMapping, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0,0, 0 );
if (pFileData == NULL)
{
    printf("%d [ERR] cant mapview of file %d\n",GetCurrentThreadId(),GetLastError());
    return -1;
}
pLogMsg = LogPrint();//returns a null terminated string
memcpy(pFileData,pLogMsg,strlen(pLogMsg));
pFileData += strlen(pLogMsg); 
free(pLogMsg);
```

Comment: as general note `hMapping == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` - this is error. `CreateFileMapping` return 0 on fail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all `CreateFileMapping` and `MapViewOfFile` this is bad solution for log file. you need create/open file with `FILE_APPEND_DATA` access instead `GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE` - so call must look like:

```
HANDLE log_file = CreateFileW(L"one.txt", 
    FILE_APPEND_DATA,
    FILE_SHARE_WRITE|FILE_SHARE_READ,     
    NULL,
    OPEN_ALWAYS,                 
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,   
    NULL);
```

in this case you open file with `FILE_APPEND_DATA` and `SYNCHRONIZE` (because no `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED`):

> If the caller sets only the **FILE_APPEND_DATA** and **SYNCHRONIZE** flags, it
>   can write only to the end of the file, and any offset information
>   about write operations to the file is ignored. The file will
>   automatically be extended as necessary for this type of operation.

after this you need log via `WriteFile` - it will be automatically append to the end of file. this is what exactly need for log file.

however, if want use `CreateFileMapping` and `MapViewOfFile` - at first  `CreateFileMapping` return 0 on error, so check 
`if (hMapping == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)` is wrong

if you want change file size - you need use for this [`SetFileInformationByHandle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365539(v=vs.85).aspx) with [`FileEndOfFileInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364228(v=vs.85).aspx) (vista+)or [`NtSetInformationFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff567096(v=vs.85).aspx) with `FileEndOfFileInformation` (working everywhere, how not hard understand `SetFileInformationByHandle` is only very thin shell over `NtSetInformationFile` or `ZwSetInformationFile` (in user mode this is the same function)). use `SetFilePointer` followed by `SetEndOfFile` also possible but bad and not effective choice - you will be have 2 calls in src code instead on single. in binary - you will even more worse situation: first you set file position, that `SetEndOfFile` read this file position and finally call `NtSetInformationFile` with this position. so 3 calls instead one. and assume that nobody change file position (on this handle) between `SetFilePointer` and `SetEndOfFile` calls

but need clear understand that call `SetFileInformationByHandle` with `FileEndOfFileInfo` you can only after you unmap view and close section. otherwise you got error `ERROR_USER_MAPPED_FILE` (`STATUS_USER_MAPPED_FILE` )

> If **CreateFileMapping** is called to create a file mapping object for
>   hFile, **UnmapViewOfFile** must be called first to unmap all views and
>   call **CloseHandle** to close the file mapping object before you can
>   call **SetEndOfFile**.

Answer (score 1):

There is no 'end of file' marker within the file.  You need to set the file length, so the OS marks it correctly.

See MSDN documentation for [SetEndOfFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365531(v=vs.85).aspx)

`Sets the physical file size for the specified file to the current position of the file pointer.`

Comment: [`SetFilePointer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365541(v=vs.85).aspx) is probably also needed.

Comment: SetEndOfFile after the write didnt solve the problem

Comment: @DhyanDeepA.K - you probably not unmap view and close section before try set file size and got `ERROR_USER_MAPPED_FILE`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set the end-of-file marker through a file mapping. The end-of-file marker does not physically exist in a file. It is a flag raised by the OS when reading past the end of a file.

To set the size of a file you will have to call [SetFilePointer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365541.aspx) followed by [SetEndOfFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365531.aspx) on the file object used to create the file mapping.